# Django html extends tags

Tags: html, django, extends

This is my base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  </head>
  <body>

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}


  </body>
</html>
```

This is home_page where I am using the {% extends 'base.html' %}

```
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <img src="{% static 'img/myImage.jpg' %}" class='img-fluid'>

  </div>

  {% if premium_content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Premium</h1>
      {{ premium_content }}

    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

The here is my views.py where I have the home_page and before using the extends tag I could render this page properly

```
def home_page(request):
    context = {

        "title":"Hello World We Working"

    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context["premium_content"] = 'Only premium users see this'

    return render(request, 'MainApp/home_page.html', context)
```

The error message that I am getting is `TemplateDoesNotExist at /` Which I do not understand I even tried putting the two html files in the same directory but still I get the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create templates file in your project or app directory and update TEMPLATES variable in the settings.py like below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       ...

        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

       ...

    },
]
```

And then put your HTML files on the templates directory
I hope this works for you

Comment: i have already created the templates file, unless you mean that I should have 2 templates?

Comment: No I mean is that you should create templates directory in your app directory and then put all of your HTML files on the templates directory.